# Xml to html using xslt of inspect code of VS Projects

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a an `InspectionResults.xml` which gets generated when I run `inspectcode.exe` from `JetbrainsCommandLine Tool Analysis`. Is there any `xslt` file provided by the `Jetbrains` to convert this xml to html. I was able to convert `DuplicateReport.xml` to `html` using the `xslt` provided by them. Does Jetbrains provide one for this conversion. If not please help me out.

My xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generated by JetBrains Inspect Code 9.1 -->
<Report ToolsVersion="102.0">
<Information>
<Solution>Server\Server.sln</Solution>
<InspectionScope>
 <Element>Solution</Element>
</InspectionScope>
</Information>
<IssueTypes>
<IssueType Id="ArrangeStaticMemberQualifier" Category="Code Style" Description="Add/remove qualifier for static members" Severity="WARNING" />
<IssueType Id="ArrangeThisQualifier" Category="Code Style" Description="Add/remove 'this.' qualifier" Severity="WARNING" />
 <IssueType Id="CSharpErrors" Category="C# Compiler Errors" Description="" Severity="ERROR" />
 </IssueTypes>

  <Issues>
  <Project Name="Common">
  <Issue TypeId="RedundantUsingDirective" File="Common\AdapterAuthorizationException.cs" Offset="15-48" Line="2" Message="Using directive is not required by the code and can be safely removed" />
  <Issue TypeId="RedundantUsingDirective" File="Common\AdapterAuthorizationException.cs" Offset="50-68" Line="3" Message="Using directive is not required by the code and can be safely removed" />
  <Issue TypeId="CSharpErrors" File="Common\AdapterAuthorizationException.cs" Offset="63-67" Line="3" Message="Cannot resolve symbol 'Linq'" />
  </Project>
  </Issues>
  </Report>
```

Comment: This seems a bit off topic - have you tried contacting JetBrains support?  If you're looking for help with XSLT, you should post the XSLT you've attempted - but it sounds like you're looking for a product from another website.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this **inspectcode.xslt** that is mentioned in the overview features of the Resharper Command Line Tools, and is working just fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:key name="ISSUETYPES" match="/Report/Issues/Project/Issue" use="@TypeId"/>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="TopLevelReport">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Resharper InspectCode Report</title>

        <style>
        body { font-family: Arial; }
        th, td { text-align: left; }
        .severity { font-weight: bold; }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Resharper InspectCode Report</h1>

        <xsl:for-each select="/Report/IssueTypes/IssueType">
          <h2>
            <span class="severity"><xsl:value-of select="@Severity"/></span>: <xsl:value-of select="@Description"/>
          </h2>
          <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
              <th>File</th>
              <th>Line Number</th>
              <th>Message</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('ISSUETYPES',@Id)">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@File"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@Line"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@Message"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </table>
          <br />
          <hr />
          <br />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This content was taken from:

https://gist.github.com/maartenba/b7b1866d11a54cf3bc9f04316afa1a9e

The overview of the features is here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/ReSharper_Command_Line_Tools.html
and in that video is where this `xslt` is mentioned

And in case you need a Tools to apply this XSLT see this question and answers

[Are there any XSLT processing command line tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527112/are-there-any-xslt-processing-command-line-tools)